# Edit python script used as Data entry in Power BI

Tags: python, powerbi

I have a python script and used it to create a dataframe in Power BI.

Now I want to edit that dataframe in Power BI but don´t enter from scratch as new data because I want to keep all the charts inside my Power BI model.

For example in my old dataframe i specified some dates inside my script so the information was limited to those dates. Now i want to change the dates to new ones but dont want to lose all the model.

df = df

Comment: can you clarify the question its not quite clear? do you want to keep the old df and add a new df with new dates to the existing data? or just update the dates in the current data frame?

Comment: @JUAN VAN WERSCH ANTUNEZ How did my suggestion work out for you?

Comment: I open Power BI -->New Source: Python, then i copy paste a python script and then get a dataframe from it. Sometimes i want to edit that script without changing the type of data or number of columns, but filter information, for example, for some dates but dont want to loose all the work inside the Power BI report, but update it with the new information. (by the way, sorry for the late answer, I was out for a week)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you're not dong this in a PowerBI Python Visual. If you're using Python under the Transform tab in the Power Query Editor, the key to your problem lies not in Python itself, but rather in the reference function available to you if you right-click the table under queries in the Power Query Editor:

[image]

Try this:

**1:** Save the following sample data in a csv as `C:\pbidata\src.csv` file and load it into PowerBI using `Get Data > Text/Csv`

```
A,B,C
1,1*0,100
2,20,200
3,30,300
```

**2:** Display it as a table:

[image]

**3:** Open the Power Query Editor through `Edit Queries`

[image]

**4:** Add some Python

Here you can insert a Python snippet after the `Changed type` step under `Applied steps` with `Transform > Run Python Script`. Inserting the following example code:

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
import pandas as pd
df=dataset.copy(deep=True)
df['D']=df['C']*2
```

... will give you this:

[image]

**5:** And let's say that you're happy with this for now and that you'd like to make a plot out of it back on the Power BI Desktop. I'm using a clustered bar chart to get this:

[image]

**6:** Now, like you're saying, if you'd like to have `df['D']=df['C']/4` instead, but retain the same dataset, Python script and figure `Plot 1, Py script 1`, go back to the Power Query Editor and use the functionality that I mentioned in the beginning:

[image]

**7:** And add another Python snippet:

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
import pandas as pd
df=dataset.copy(deep=True)
df['D']=df['D']/4
```

And there we go:

[image]

Now you have two different Python snippets that build on the same dataset. You still have the data from the first snippet, and you can do whatever you want with the second snippet without messing up your data source.

**8:** Insert another chart to verify:

[image]

**9:** Maybe have some fun with the whole thing by changing the source file:

**Data:**

```
A,B,C
100,10,100
2,20,200
3,30,150
```

**New plots:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But my problem is with the source of information. Each day i get new info in my database, so with a python script I get what i want from that DB and change some dates to extract info. Then i use power bi --> New Source: Python and I copy paste a python script and get a dataframe from it. I want to edit that script sometimes (without changing the type of info or the number of column, just filter data) and keep all the interactions inside power bi that this dataframe has.

Comment: @JUANVANWERSCHANTUNEZ I still think you could use my suggested approach. Or a version of it. If you're interested we could do a chat session for further details thursday or friday. I'm away from the PC for a few days.

Comment: You are right! It's better to work my data as you say. I can import SQL Tables/Views into Power BI and then run scripts to create new measures inside Power BI.Thanks, very useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the python scripts doing the following steps:

- Open Query Editor
- At 'Applied steps', the first one, source, contains a small gear symbol just on the right side, click on it.

You can change the script direct into Power Query.